# Count Words For the SharePoint List Item

Tags: jquery, list-form, rich-text

I need to count the words of SharePoint List Item.  I have used code, but it shows me only 0 words though I type several words.  When I used an alert for holdtextvalue it shows me blank value.  Can one tell me what is the problem?

```
$(document).ready(function()
  {  var holdtextvalue;

     $("#ctl00_m_g_2ff37816_5d5b_42e8_b189_77daaaf2bc56_ff31_ctl00_ctl00_TextField_inplacerte").keyup(function()
     {
        holdtextvalue=$.trim($('txt1').val())
        alert("The value is::"+holdtextvalue);
        var count=holdtextvalue.split(/[\s\.\?]+/).length
         alert(count); 
         return false;  

      });
});
```

Comment: If `txt1` is input id, you must use `$("#txt1")`, your current selector selects all tags with name 'txt1', which is not correct

Comment: The question is a little confusing. As I understand the problem is more jQuery/javascript related rather than a SPListItem field.

Answer (score 1):

If your textfield looks something like this:

```
<input name="..." 
    type="text" value="Jordan" 
    id="ctl00_m_g_2ff37816_5d5b_42e8_b189_77daaaf2bc56_ff31_ctl00_ctl00_TextField_inplacerte">
```

Then you can retrieve the value of this input like Kai mentioned with jQuery id selector:

```
holdtextvalue=$.trim($('#ctl00_m_g_2ff37816_5d5b_42e8_b189_77daaaf2bc56_ff31_ctl00_ctl00_TextField_inplacerte').val())
```